# Number of free real parameters in Hermitian vs unitary matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, spectral-theory, unitary-matrices, hermitian-matrices

There seems consensus that the number of free real parameters of an $n \times n$ Hermitian matrix $M$ is $n^2$; see e.g. [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/110189/number-of-parameters-needed-to-specify-a-hermitian-matrix-of-rank-r) and also [this short note](https://www.physics.mcgill.ca/%7Eyangob/groups.pdf).

On the other hand, such a matrix has a spectral decomposition $M = U D(\lambda) U^*$, where $U$ is an $n\times n$ unitary matrix, $U^*$ its adjoint, and $D(\lambda)$ is the diagonal matrix with entries $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^n$.  There are also posts, such as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1398789/number-of-independent-components-of-a-unitary-matrix), suggesting that the number of free real parameters of an $n\times n$ unitary matrix is also $n^2$.  Yet for "generic" Hermitian matrices $M$, the entries of $\lambda$ are distinct, and the spectral decomposition $M = U D(\lambda) U^*$ will be unique.  Thus, specifying $M$ would seem to uniquely specify $n^2 + n$ real parameters, implying that the number of free real parameters of $M$ should be $n^2 + n$.

I suspect I'm missing something basic that would resolve this apparent discrepancy.  Any suggestions would be appreciated!

(I'm also interested in the rank $r$ version of this question; specifying $r$ orthonormal vectors (by the same logic as [the above post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1398789/number-of-independent-components-of-a-unitary-matrix)), and specifying a rank $r$ Hermitian matrix both appear to require $2nr - r^2$ real parameters, yet the Hermitian matrix also specifies $r$ eigenvalues.)

Comment: The decomposition $UDU^\ast$ is not unique. In fact, $UDU^\ast=U\Lambda D\Lambda^\ast U^\ast$ for every diagonal matrix $\Lambda$ whose diagonal entries lie on the unit circle. So, one can always assume that the top row of $U$ is real. This saves up $n$ real parameters for the imaginary parts of the entries on the top row.

Comment: Aha, I had failed to see that eigenvectors are only unique up to a phase.  (For others: see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/522085/unique-of-eigenbasis-of-self-adjoint-operator).)  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can refer to the literature about the Lie group and Lie algebra. Particularly, any unitary $U$ can be uniquely represented by its derivative $H$ in the Riemman space in the exponential formula, namely, $U=e^{-itH}$, where $t$ is a fixed constant and $H$ is a Hermitian matrix. In this regard, it is easy to see that a unitary $U$ has the same free real parameters as the Hermitian matrix $H$.